# Changing background color of selected cell?

Tags: iphone, uitableview, colors, background, tableview

Does anyone know how to change the background color of a cell using UITableViewCell, for each selected cell? I created this UITableViewCell inside the code for TableView.

Answer (score 96):

Changing the property selectedBackgroundView is correct and the simplest way. I use the following code to change the selection color:

```
// set selection color
UIView *myBackView = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:cell.frame];
myBackView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:1 green:1 blue:0.75 alpha:1];
cell.selectedBackgroundView = myBackView;
[myBackView release];
```

Comment: Yeah, but this does not look good in UITableViewStyleGrouped when selecting first or last cell in the section.

Comment: @manicaesar but it still works on iOS7+ :) There are no more rounded corners in `UITableViewStyleGrouped` mode

Answer (score 40):

I finally managed to get this to work in a table view with style set to Grouped.

First set the `selectionStyle` property of all cells to `UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone`.

```
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
```

Then implement the following in your table view delegate:

```
static NSColor *SelectedCellBGColor = ...;
static NSColor *NotSelectedCellBGColor = ...;

- (NSIndexPath *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    NSIndexPath *currentSelectedIndexPath = [tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
    if (currentSelectedIndexPath != nil)
    {
        [[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:currentSelectedIndexPath] setBackgroundColor:NotSelectedCellBGColor];
    }

    return indexPath;
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    [[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] setBackgroundColor:SelectedCellBGColor];
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (cell.isSelected == YES)
    {
        [cell setBackgroundColor:SelectedCellBGColor];
    }
    else
    {
        [cell setBackgroundColor:NotSelectedCellBGColor];
    }
}
```

Comment: this is the best answer!

Comment: I am sorry to inform you, but your solution does not work, xcode 5, iOS7

Comment: @SAFAD Just implemented this under iOS7/Xcode 5 for a Plain UITableView. I had to employ additional logic in `cellForRowAtIndexPath:` to handle displaying the selected cell properly after the cell had been scrolled back into view, so that may be your problem.

Comment: Don't you also need to override didDeselectRowAtIndexPath?

Comment: @EvanR What kind of additional logic did you add?

Comment: @Keeano It was a while ago, but I believe in `tableView:cellForRowAtIndexPath:` I added something along the lines of `if ([indexPath isEqual:[tableView indexPathForSelectedRow]]) { cell.selected = YES; } else { cell.selected = NO; }

Comment: willDisplayCell is helped for my default selected cell of tableview for changing text color when default selected cell is selected.

Comment: This answer should be accepted, I just used it today and it worked for me

Answer (score 21):

## SWIFT 4, XCODE 9, IOS 11

After some testing this **WILL** remove the background color when deselected or cell is tapped a second time when table view Selection is set to "Multiple Selection". Also works when table view Style is set to "Grouped".

```
extension ViewController: UITableViewDelegate {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) {
            cell.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGray
        }
    }
}
```

> Note: In order for this to work as you see below, your cell's Selection property can be set to anything BUT None.

## How it looks with different options

Style: **Plain**, Selection: **Single Selection**

[image: Single Selection]

Style: **Plain**, Selection: **Multiple Selection**

[image: Multiple Selection]

Style: **Grouped**, Selection: **Multiple Selection**

[image: Grouped Multiple Selection]

## Bonus - Animation

For a smoother color transition, try some animation:

```
extension ViewController: UITableViewDelegate {
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) {
            UIView.animate(withDuration: 0.3, animations: {
                cell.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.darkGray
            })
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Animated color transition]

## Bonus - Text and Image Changing

You may notice the icon and text color also changing when cell is selected. This happens automatically when you set the UIImage and UILabel Highlighted properties

**UIImage**

1. Supply two colored images:

[image: Two colored images]

2. Set the Highlighted image property:

[image: Highlighted property]

**UILabel**

Just supply a color for the Highlighted property:

[image: Highlighted Color]

Comment: thanks for the Bonus - Text and Image Changing. First time to know about label highlighted usage

Comment: I have plain style, and I have Single selection but I have custom cell and the behavior is like when I click on item, it gets colored background but when I click another cell, the background of first item never goes back.  Why it is so??

Comment: @MarkMoeykens when I implemented the above with each one of the  storyboard settings, the cell did not "unselect" after I press on it  a second time ... even though I have a block of code explicity setting its color to white

Comment: I am looking for OSX solution. I am able to change cell colour but not able to hide/unhide button inside cells. Any help?

Answer (score 19):

```
// animate between regular and selected state
- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated {

    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

    if (selected) {
        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:234.0f/255 green:202.0f/255 blue:255.0f/255 alpha:1.0f];
    }
    else {
        self.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];
    }
}
```

Comment: I tried doing this but setting `self.backgroundView` to alternating images for either scenario—was not able to get it to work.  I even tried putting `self.selectedBackgroundView` in `if (selected)` and `nil`ing each view out first. Trying to figure out what I'm missing here! Ultimately had to do it by changing `self.backgroundView` in the `if` statement and calling `self.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithPatternImage:[UIImage imageNamed:]]` in the `else` statement.

Answer (score 12):

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

     UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
     cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];

}
```

Comment: The problem with this is that the other rows that were previously selected would still have that new background color.

Comment: @vnchopra, I think this may have changed since 2013 but I just tried this and it does get removed when you select another cell. (Xcode 9, iOS 11, Swift 4)

Answer (score 11):

I created UIView and set the property of cell selectedBackgroundView:

```
UIView *v = [[UIView alloc] init];
v.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
cell.selectedBackgroundView = v;
```

Comment: For a solution that works (properly) with `UIAppearance` for iOS 7 (and higher?) using its default `selectedBackgroundView` to set the color, take a look at my [answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/32208591/2471006) to  similar question.

Answer (score 7):

If you're talking about selected cells, the property is `-selectedBackgroundView`. This will be shown when the user selects your cell.

Answer (score 6):

I've had luck with the following:

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView willDisplayCell:(UITableViewCell *)cell forRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    bool isSelected = // enter your own code here
    if (isSelected)
    {
        [cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:1 green:1 blue:0.75 alpha:1]];
        [cell setAccessibilityTraits:UIAccessibilityTraitSelected];
    }
    else
    {
        [cell setBackgroundColor:[UIColor clearColor]];
        [cell setAccessibilityTraits:0];
    }
}
```

Answer (score 6):

I have a highly customized UITableViewCell. So I implemented my own cell selection.

```
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone;
```

I created a method in my cell's class:

```
- (void)highlightCell:(BOOL)highlight
{
    if (highlight) {
        self.contentView.backgroundColor = RGB(0x355881);
        _bodyLabel.textColor = RGB(0xffffff);
        _fromLabel.textColor = RGB(0xffffff);
        _subjectLabel.textColor = RGB(0xffffff);
        _dateLabel.textColor = RGB(0xffffff);
    }
    else {
        self.contentView.backgroundColor = RGB(0xf7f7f7);;
        _bodyLabel.textColor = RGB(0xaaaaaa);
        _fromLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        _subjectLabel.textColor = [UIColor blackColor];
        _dateLabel.textColor = RGB(0x496487);
    }
}
```

In my UITableViewController class in ViewWillAppear added this:

```
NSIndexPath *tableSelection = [self.tableView indexPathForSelectedRow];
SideSwipeTableViewCell *cell = (SideSwipeTableViewCell*)[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:tableSelection];
[cell highlightCell:NO];
```

In didSelectRow added this:

```
SideSwipeTableViewCell *cell = (SideSwipeTableViewCell*)[self.tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
[cell highlightCell:YES];
```

Answer (score 6):

I was able to solve this problem by creating a subclass of `UITableViewCell` and implementing the setSelected:animated: method

```
- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated {
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

    // Configure the view for the selected state
    if(selected) {
        [self setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];
        [self setBackgroundColor:[UIColor greenColor]];
    } else {
        [self setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];
    }
}
```

The trick was setting the

```
cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleDefault;
```

in the implementing view controller and then in the tableViewCell setting it as

```
[self setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];
```

Hope this helps. :)

Comment: I confirm this works well. In my custom cell subclass initWithCoder I set the selection style to none and then customise the colours etc in setSelected based upon if it is selected.

Answer (score 6):

For iOS7+ and if you are using **Interface Builder** then subclass your cell and implement:

**Objective-C**

```
- (void)awakeFromNib {
    [super awakeFromNib];
    // Default Select background
    UIView *v = [[UIView alloc] init];
    v.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    self.selectedBackgroundView = v;
}
```

**Swift 2.2**

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Default Select background
    self.selectedBackgroundView = { view in
        view.backgroundColor = .redColor()
        return view
    }(UIView())
}
```

Answer (score 5):

This worked perfectly with grouped calls: Implement a custom subclass of `UITableViewCell`

This will respect corners and such...

```
- (void)setSelected:(BOOL)selected animated:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super setSelected:selected animated:animated];

    if(selected)
        [self setBackgroundColor:[UIColor colorWithRed:(245/255.0) green:(255/255.0) blue:(255/255.0) alpha:1]];
    else
        [self setBackgroundColor:[UIColor whiteColor]];

}
```

Comment: Thanks this works, but don't forget to set UITableViewCell "Selection" to "None" instead of default, otherwise the default gray background would keep showing up.

Answer (score 5):

If you just want to remove the grey background color do this :

```
-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
     [[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath] setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];
}
```

Answer (score 4):

The default style is gray and it destroys the colors of the cell if it was done programmatically. You can do this to avoid that. (in Swift)
`cell.selectionStyle = .None`

Comment: the swift 4 version  of the solution is                                                                                      
      cell?.selectionStyle = .none

Answer (score 3):

Check out `AdvancedTableViewCells` in [Apple's sample code](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/AdvancedTableViewCells/Introduction/Intro.html).

You'll want to use the composite cell pattern.

Answer (score 3):

In **Swift**

```
let v = UIView()
    v.backgroundColor = self.darkerColor(color)
    cell?.selectedBackgroundView = v;

...

func darkerColor( color: UIColor) -> UIColor {
    var h = CGFloat(0)
    var s = CGFloat(0)
    var b = CGFloat(0)
    var a = CGFloat(0)
    let hueObtained = color.getHue(&h, saturation: &s, brightness: &b, alpha: &a)
    if hueObtained {
        return UIColor(hue: h, saturation: s, brightness: b * 0.75, alpha: a)
    }
    return color
}
```

Comment: This is definitely the best modern answer, because setting the selection style to .None and using the "willSelectRow" and "didSelectRow" delegate methods has the side effect that a long press on a row will not highlight it as selected, which is the default behavior for normal styling.

Answer (score 3):

Works for me

```
UIView *customColorView = [[UIView alloc] init];
    customColorView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:180/255.0 
                                                      green:138/255.0 
                                                       blue:171/255.0 
                                                      alpha:0.5];
    cell.selectedBackgroundView =  customColorView;
```

Answer (score 3):

in Swift 3, converted from illuminates answer.

```
override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
    if(selected) {
        self.selectionStyle = .none
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.green
    } else {
        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.blue
    }
}
```

(however the view only changes once the selection is confirmed by releasing your finger)

Answer (score 3):

**Swift 5.3**

Here I did for a single row without creating a class for the cell.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) {
        cell.contentView.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 0.1411764771, green: 0.3960784376, blue: 0.5647059083, alpha: 1)
    }
}
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    if let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) {
        cell.contentView.backgroundColor = #colorLiteral(red: 1, green: 1, blue: 1, alpha: 1)
    }
}
```

Comment: I am looking for OSX solution. I am able to change cell colour but not able to hide/unhide button inside cells. Any help?

Answer (score 2):

Create a custom UITableViewCell. Inside you custom class override the "setSelected" function and change the **contentView** background color.
You can also override you "setHighlighted" function.

In Swift:

```
class myTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
        // Initialization code
    }

    override func setSelected(selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

        // Configure the view for the selected state
        // Add your color here
        self.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    }

    override func setHighlighted(highlighted: Bool, animated: Bool) {
        // Add your color here
        self.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

```
override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)

    if selected {
        self.contentView.backgroundColor = .black
    } else {
        self.contentView.backgroundColor = .white
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**Swift 3, 4, 5 select cell background colour**

1) Change only highlighted colour when user click on cell:

1.1) Inside cell class:

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    // Initialization code

    let backgroundView = UIView()
    backgroundView.backgroundColor = UIColor.init(white: 1.0, alpha: 0.1)
    selectedBackgroundView = backgroundView
}
```

1.2) Viewcontroller that you use customized cell

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
}
```

2) If you to set colour for selected cells:

```
override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
    // Configure the view for the selected state

    if selected {
        self.backgroundColor = .darkGray
    } else {
        self.backgroundColor = .white
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

Here is a quick way to do this right in Interface Builder (within a Storyboard). Drag a simple UIView to the top of your UITableView as in [image: UIView]
Next connect your cell's `selectedBackgroundView` Outlet to this view. You can even connect multiple cells' outlets to this one view. 
[image: Cell's outlet]

Comment: no, that's not a good deal. if u do this ... there is only one instance for each cell. U r not able to select more then one item with this solution

Comment: Yeah this method looks good, but the view gets shared and you get a flash as it jumps to the next cell

Answer (score 1):

For a solution that works (properly) with `UIAppearance` for **iOS 7** (and higher?) by subclassing `UITableViewCell` and using its default `selectedBackgroundView` to set the color, take a look at **my answer to a similar question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32208591/2471006)**.

Answer (score 1):

```
- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didHighlightRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.contentView.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
}

- (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didUnhighlightRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    UITableViewCell *cell = (UITableViewCell *)[tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:indexPath];
    cell.contentView.backgroundColor = nil;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I have tried each one among above answers, but none of them best fits for me,

then i have looked into one of the native provided method, and it is working fine.

first, make cellSelectionStyle to None and then go for this solution.

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDeselectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> IndexPath?
{   
    let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath);

   //cell which is getting deselected, make whatever changes that are required to make it back normal        

    cell.backgroundColor = kNormalColor;

    return indexPath;
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> IndexPath?
{
    let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath);

   //cell which is getting selected, make whatever changes that are required to make it selected        

    cell.backgroundColor = kSelectedColor;

    return indexPath;
}
```

advantage of this methods over other all is :

1. It works for multiple cell selection
2. You can change any element, whichever you want, not only background color of given cell when it get selected as well as deselected.

Answer (score 0):

```
var last_selected:IndexPath!
```

define last_selected:IndexPath inside the class

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) as! Cell
    cell.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
    cell.txt.textColor = UIColor.red

    if(last_selected != nil){
        //deselect
        let deselect_cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: last_selected) as! Cell
        deselect_cell.contentView.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
        deselect_cell.txt.textColor = UIColor.black
    }

    last_selected = indexPath
}
```

Comment: I am looking for OSX solution. I am able to change cell colour but not able to hide/unhide button inside cells. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

Set selection property to None, make sure tableView has 'Single Selection' set and use this method in `tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell` delegate method:

```
extension UITableViewCell {
    func setSelectionColor(isSelected: Bool, selectionColor: UIColor, nonSelectionColor: UIColor) {
        contentView.backgroundColor = isSelected ? selectionColor : nonSelectionColor
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**SWIFT 5.X** 
It also works when *accessoryType* changed for cell

```
extension UITableViewCell{
    var selectedBackgroundColor: UIColor?{
        set{
            let customColorView = UIView()
            customColorView.backgroundColor = newValue
            selectedBackgroundView = customColorView
        }
        get{
            return selectedBackgroundView?.backgroundColor
        }
    }
}
```

And in UIViewController use like below...

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! myCell
    cell.selectedBackgroundColor = UIColor.lightGray
    return cell
  }
```

Comment: I am looking for OSX solution. I am able to change cell colour but not able to hide/unhide button inside cells. Any help?

Answer (score 0):

I had a recent issue with an update to Swift 5 where the table view would flash select and then deselect the selected cell. I tried several of the solutions here and none worked. **The solution is setting `clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear` to false.**

I had previously used the UIView and selectedBackgroundColor property, so I kept with that approach.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
  let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "popoverCell", for: indexPath) as! PopoverCell

  let backgroundView = UIView()
  backgroundView.backgroundColor = Color.Blue
  cell.selectedBackgroundView = backgroundView
}
```

Below are the changes I needed for Swift 5. The property `clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear` was the reason my cells were deselecting. The following select was necessary on first load.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
  super.viewDidLoad()

  clearsSelectionOnViewWillAppear = false
  popoverTableView.selectRow(at: selectedIndexPath, animated: false, scrollPosition: .none)
}
```

Comment: I am looking for OSX solution. I am able to change cell colour but not able to hide/unhide button inside cells. Any help?