# Table View Cell Default Background Color - what sets the default colour?

Tags: ios, tableview, cell

When I load a TableView the default cell background color of the highlighted cell is light grey. 
How and where do I change this to another color?

Comment: are you loading from nib or through you are trying to create the instance of cell?

Comment: See this post: http://stackoverflow.com/a/2025099/1694129

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2418189/iphone-uitableviewcell-changing-background-color-of-selected-cell

Comment: Have you scanned the docs for `UITableViewCell`?

Comment: Will work through these later - many thanks - it's the highlighted colour not the general background. When I press a cell I can dictate it with code like UIView *selectionView = [[UIView alloc] init];
selectionView.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
cell.selectedBackgroundView = selectionView; but it's the first time it loads that it defaults to gray.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set selectionStyle for cell in method:

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

// Code to initialize your cell
    cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyleBlue;
    return cell;

}
```

Answer (score 1):

We can set selected backgroundView in this method

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
```

with thesse lines

```
UIView *selectionView = [[UIView alloc] init];
selectionView.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
cell.selectedBackgroundView = selectionView;
```

Comment: No - that routine works fine when you move cell focus after the page has loaded. My questions is how you alter the background colour of the selected cell when the page loads. The default is gray and I want to change it to say yellow.

Comment: Getting muddled: - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath paints the screen when the page loads and - (void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath deals with each time you press a new cell. Apologies