# How to change the selected cell background color without missing the text

Tags: ios, uitableview, colors, background

I want to change the selected cell background color and keep the text on that cell. Then I did like this, it can change the cell color but the text on the cell will disappear.

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"MessageCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    cell.textLabel.text = [self.receivedData objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];

    return cell;
}

-(void)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView didSelectRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath{

    static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"MessageCell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier forIndexPath:indexPath];

    UIView *bgColorView = [[UIView alloc]init];
    bgColorView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.529 green:0.808 blue:0.922 alpha:0.5];

    cell.selectedBackgroundView = bgColorView;

}
```

Comment: What color is the text?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Changing background color of selected cell?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2418189/iphone-uitableviewcell-changing-background-color-of-selected-cell)

Comment: You shouldn't be dequeuing a new cell. Get a reference to the cell you selected using the table view method, cellForRowAtIndexPath:.

Answer (score 0):

You are replacing the current view (the one that has got your text in it) with a new instance of UIView (with no text in it, but your new color). That is why your text is disappearing. You should change the background color property of selectedBackgroundview like so:

```
cell.selectedBackgroundView.backgroundColor = [UIColor colorWithRed:0.529 green:0.808 blue:0.922 alpha:0.5];
```

Although I think you can even ditch the `selectedBackgroundView` part and just do `cell.backgroundColor = ...` in `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`