# Custom UI TableViewCell selected backgroundcolor swift

Tags: swift, uitableview, selected

I am trying to change the appearance of a custom selected TableViewCell using Swift.

Do I need to do it via the designer or programmatically?

I tried the following:

[image]

And here is my code:

```
@IBOutlet var tableView: UITableView!


    var tableData: [String] = ["One", "Two", "Three", "Four"]

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()


        // Register custom cell
        var nib = UINib(nibName: "vwTblCell", bundle: nil)
        tableView.registerNib(nib, forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell")

    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return self.tableData.count
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell     {

        var cell:TblCell = self.tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell") as TblCell

        cell.lblCarName.text = tableData[indexPath.row]
        cell.imgCarName.image = UIImage(named: tableData[indexPath.row])

        return cell

    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) {
        println("Row \(indexPath.row) selected")
    }

    func tableView(tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 70
    }
```

Comment: Just set the cell's `selectedBackgroundView`

Answer (score 15, accepted):

You've the right method already in there: `didSelectRowAtIndexPath`. In that method you can call `tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath)` and get your cell. Than you can set the cell-background to your color:

```
 func tableView(tableView: UITableView!, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath!) {
        println("Row \(indexPath.row) selected")
        let cell:YourCustomCell = tableView.cellForRowAtIndexPath(indexPath) as YourCell
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
    }
```

Or, a better way would be to check in your `cellForRowAtIndexPath` method, if a cell is selected:

```
if(cell.selected){
  cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()
}else{
  cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
}
```

Comment: Thanks :) this is in the right direction. I have a problem though: When I click on a cell it becomes it's original grey selection color, when I click the next cell the previously selected cell does become red. But the currently selected cell is always grey.

Comment: Did you try the first idea?

Comment: I tried both, behaviour was the same for either method.

Comment: I can't Test it at the moment. But that's the way to go for you.

Comment: Added: "var myBackView = UIView(frame: cell.frame); cell.selectedBackgroundView = myBackView;" to your code. now it works.

Comment: This is probably what everyone is looking for: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26895370/swift-uitableviewcell-selected-background-color-on-multiple-selection

Answer (score 26):

I have a likeness problem. In your **cellForRowAtIndexPath** method set:

```
cell.selectionStyle = .None
```

and then set **didHighlightRowAtIndexPath**...

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didHighlightRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell  = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)
    cell!.contentView.backgroundColor = .green
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didUnhighlightRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell  = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)
    cell!.contentView.backgroundColor = .clear
}
```

Comment: it works, but only the first time you click the cell :(

Comment: @joe You want selection not highlighting. This is probably what you're after: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26895370/swift-uitableviewcell-selected-background-color-on-multiple-selection

Comment: Or just set the cell's `selectedBackgroundView`…

Comment: This is not a good solution because it doesn't look natural as normal selection would do. RG128's answer I think is better.

Answer (score 20):

My two cents: the proper way of doing it (also visually) is to use the designated view in a (tableView)cell, that is the selectedBackgroundView property. However, you need to initialize it first with UIView()

**SWIFT 3.0**

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    self.selectedBackgroundView = UIView()
    self.selectionStyle = .default // you can also take this line out
}
```

Then you can use it in your customized cell as follows:

```
override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
    self.selectedBackgroundView!.backgroundColor = selected ? .red : nil
}
```

That's it. Of course you can also integrate the above in your UITableView functions referred to above. Check it out.

Comment: While this might work, it's not the right way to do it - `selectedBackgroundView` is only shown when the cell is selected, so there's no need to override the `setSelected` method.Just set `selectedBackgroundView?.backgroundColor = .red` in `awakeFromNib()`

Answer (score 13):

> Update for **Swift 3**

This answer is based on **Cao Yong** answer, and it is intended as an update for **Swift 3**

For **Swift 3**, use the following code in your **cellForRowAt indexPath** method set:

```
cell.selectionStyle = .none
```

Then, set it in **didHighlightRowAtIndexPath**

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didHighlightRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell  = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)
    cell!.contentView.backgroundColor = .red
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didUnhighlightRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell  = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)
    cell!.contentView.backgroundColor = .clear
}
```

Comment: No need for this - just set the cell's `selectedBackgroundView`

Comment: This is not a good solution because it doesn't look natural as normal selection would do. RG128's answer I think is better.

Answer (score 13):

### The correct (more native & natural) way to do it:

```
override func awakeFromNib() {
    super.awakeFromNib()
    selectedBackgroundView = UIView()
    selectedBackgroundView?.backgroundColor = .blue
}
```

Why other approaches are wrong:

1. **Highlight** solution: highlight is not select. Highlight doesn't animate as Selection does. It doesn't feel natural as a normal Selection would do
2. No need to change the color of selectedBackgroundView in `setSelected` method, because iOS handles the animation for us.
3. Setting `backgroundColor` also doesn't behave the same as iOS does it

Answer (score 8):

When you tap a cell, a subviews background color is actually being changed. That subview is 'selectedBackgroundView'. You can override the view of each cell in the cellForRowAtIndexPath TableView delegate method.

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

   let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("identifier", forIndexPath: indexPath) 

   let selectedView = UIView()
   selectedView.backgroundColor = UIColor(red: 250/255, green: 250/255, blue:     250/255, alpha: 1.0)
   cell.selectedBackgroundView = selectedView

   return cell
}
```

Change the color to whatever you like.

Comment: Amazing - all these upvoted answers and only one got it correct! Even better would be to do this in `awakeFromNib` in a custom cell, or set drag a view in and set in the storyboard.

Answer (score 6):

To keep your code clean you should think about moving screen design related code for your cells from `UITableViewController` into a `UITableViewCell` class.

Your UITableViewController` needs only to set the selected state of the cell as follows:

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath)
{
    guard let cell = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath) else { return }
    cell.setSelected(true, animated: true)
}
```

Your desired customisation can be implemented in a derrived `UITableViewCell` class by overriding `var isSelected`. With this solution you could have even different select colors for each cell.

```
class MyTableViewCell: UITableViewCell
{
    @IBOutlet weak var label:UILabel!

    override var isSelected: Bool
    {
        didSet{
            if (isSelected)
            {
                self.backgroundColor = UIColor.red
                if let label = label
                {
                    label.textColor = UIColor.white
                }
            }
            else
            {
                self.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
                if let label = label
                {
                    label.textColor = UIColor.black
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

**SWIFT 5 Update**

Set the selection style to .none in the `cellForRowAT` method:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "Cell", for: indexPath) as! Cell
    cell.selectionStyle = .none

    return cell
}
```

Then implement the `didHighlightRowAt` and the `didUnhighlightRowAt` methods:

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didHighlightRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell  = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)
    cell!.contentView.backgroundColor = .red
}

func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didUnhighlightRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell  = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)
    // Add timer to be able see the effect
    Timer.scheduledTimer(withTimeInterval: 0.2, repeats: false) { (_) in
       cell!.contentView.backgroundColor = .white
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

---

## For tableView==

---

**First Call This method-**

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
        cell.textLabel?.text = "Show Label"
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()

    }
```

**And than call this method**

```
func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didDeselectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cell", forIndexPath: indexPath) as UITableViewCell
        cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    }
```

**For CollectionView==**

**1-**

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didSelectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        let cell = dateCollectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath) as! DateCollectionViewCell
            cell!.dateLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.redColor()

 }
```

**2-**

```
func collectionView(collectionView: UICollectionView, didDeselectItemAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) {
        let cell = dateCollectionView.cellForItemAtIndexPath(indexPath) as? DateCollectionViewCell
        cell!.dateLabel.backgroundColor = UIColor.clearColor()
    }
```

Comment: Or just set the cell's `selectedBackgroundView`…

Answer (score 0):

```
override func setSelected(_ selected: Bool, animated: Bool) {
    super.setSelected(selected, animated: animated)
    updateUI(isSelected: selected)
}

private func updateUI(isSelected: Bool){
   label.textColor = isSelected ? .red : .green
   //etc..
}
```

Answer (score -1):

None of above answers worked, so I try mine and it worked:
 Here it is:-

1. In your cell create function like this.

```
func reloadcell() {
    if isSelected {
        conView.backgroundColor = .yellow
    } else if isHighlighted {
        conView.backgroundColor = .yellow
    } else {
        conView.backgroundColor = .clear
    }
}
```

and call that function in layoutsubviews and in your didselect method

Answer (score -1):

In your cellForRowAtIndexPath method set:

```
cell.selectionStyle = .none
```

and then set didHighlightRowAtIndexPath like this...

```
func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didHighlightRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
    let cell  = tableView.cellForRow(at: indexPath)
    cell!.contentView.backgroundColor = .green
}
```

Comment: Please describe in more detail why the specific code is needed and provide more sample code for the first code block as it needs to be in a specific method.