# display images on collectionview inside tableview

Tags: swift, xcode, uitableview, uicollectionview

I'm trying to display images on collectionview inside tableview.

I implemented codes like so

```
 //Model
    import UIKit
    import Firebase

    struct Post {

        var key: String
        var Date: String
        var tweetImageUrl = [URL]()
        var Text: String

        init(snapshot: DataSnapshot) {

            self.key = snapshot.key
            self.Date = (snapshot.value as! NSDictionary)["Date"] as? String ?? ""
            self.Text = (snapshot.value as! NSDictionary)["Text"] as? String ?? ""
          if let urls = (snapshot.value as! NSDictionary)["tweetImageUrl"] as? [String:String] {
                 for (_,value) in urls {
              if let finalUrl = URL(string: value) {
                         tweetImageUrl.append(finalUrl)
                 }
              }
            }
         }
    }

//tableviewcell
import UIKit

class TimellineTableViewCell: UITableViewCell {

    @IBOutlet var profileImage: UIImageView!
    @IBOutlet var tempoName: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var dateLabel: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var caption: UILabel!
    @IBOutlet var collectionView: UICollectionView!

    var post: Post? {
        didSet {
            tempoName.text = "channing"
            dateLabel.text = post?.Date
            caption.text = post?.Text
            profileImage.image = #imageLiteral(resourceName: "heart")
        }
    }

    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()

        collectionView.delegate = self
        collectionView.dataSource = self
        profileImage.layer.cornerRadius = 30.0
        profileImage.layer.masksToBounds = true
    }
}//class

extension TimellineTableViewCell: UICollectionViewDelegate, UICollectionViewDataSource {

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, numberOfItemsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        guard let count = post?.tweetImageUrl.count else { return 0 }
        return count
    }

    func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, cellForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UICollectionViewCell {
        let cell = collectionView.dequeueReusableCell(withReuseIdentifier: "timeLineCell", for: indexPath) as! TimelineCollectionViewCell

        cell.configCell(post: post)

        return cell
    }
}//extension

//collectionviewcell
import UIKit

class TimelineCollectionViewCell: UICollectionViewCell {


    @IBOutlet var imageView: UIImageView!


    override func awakeFromNib() {
        super.awakeFromNib()
    }

    func configCell(post: Post?) {

        guard let imageUrl = post?.tweetImageUrl else { return }

        for url in imageUrl {

            URLSession.shared.dataTask(with: url, completionHandler: { (data, res, err) in

                guard let data = data else { return }
                let image = UIImage(data: data)

                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    self.imageView.image = image
                }
            }).resume()
        }
    }
}//class

//viewcontroller
import UIKit
import Firebase

class TimelineViewController: UIViewController, UITableViewDataSource, UITableViewDelegate {

    @IBOutlet var TimelinetableView: UITableView!

    var ref: DatabaseReference! {
        return Database.database().reference()
    }
    let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid
    var tweets = [Post]()

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        self.TimelinetableView.rowHeight = UITableViewAutomaticDimension
        self.TimelinetableView.estimatedRowHeight = 300
        fetchTweets()
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, heightForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGFloat {
        return 300
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
        return tweets.count
    }

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        let cell = TimelinetableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "tableCell", for: indexPath) as! TimellineTableViewCell

        cell.post = tweets[indexPath.row]

        return cell
    }

    func fetchTweets() {
        ref.child("TWEETS").child(uid!).observe(.value, with: { (snapshot) in

            var result = [Post]()
            for post in snapshot.children {
                let post = Post(snapshot: post as! DataSnapshot)
                result.append(post)
            }
            self.tweets = result.sorted(by: { (p1, p2) -> Bool in
                p1.Date > p2.Date
            })
            self.TimelinetableView.reloadData()            
        }, withCancel: nil)

    }//func

}//class
```

But if I run it simulator looks like this [image]

If I selected one of these cell, components come out except imageview on the collectionview. If cell is not being selected, simulator looks like a cell which says "Really fun". Does anyone have any idea how to fix this?

Comment: You can take a screenshot of part of your screen by pressing Shift-Command-4 and then dragging a box around the desired area. It looks nicer than a picture. :-) https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT201361

Comment: cell custom highlight: https://stackoverflow.com/a/31512042/2450755 cell custom selection: https://stackoverflow.com/a/27475774/2450755

Comment: Thank you stone. I'll do that next time!!

Comment: Thank you again Andrea!! But is this about background color isn't it?

Comment: Is about having the possibility to control exactly what you want to customize (background, label, anything you may have inside your cell) during the highlight/unhighlight or selection/unselection of the cell. What would you like to customize (or fix) ? From the question above, is not clear for me.

Comment: I want cell to show components properly. It shows only caption now unless cell is selected. imageview is not shown even after cell is selected. So I want to fix them and want cell to show components from scratch without selecting.

Answer (score 0):

It's about constrains not the code. So, after I gave constrains properly it worked fine.

Comment: Hi - I am stuck in the same rut as you albeit more than 2 years later. I have to code working fine but cannot get the collection view to show up properly. Do you remember what you did to get the collection view contents to appear properly?

Comment: I don't remember precisely but I think I gave constraints to the collectionvlew like how much px collectionvlew should away from bottom edge of the tablevlew. Plus I had used storyboard so I can't give you code sorry:( I hope this helps.