# How to make selection style in UITableViewCell

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, background-color

I created Xib file for my uitableviewcell in the attributed inspector i choose SelectionStyle default, but it didn't help me. So and i added accessory type .detailDisclosureButton. 
So when i tapped on a cell , My cell doesn't highlighted gray color, only disclosurebutton does

[image]

[image]

Comment: can you show your code or attributed inspector details

Comment: I added screenshot of my attributed inspector

Comment: try this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28833609/custom-ui-tableviewcell-selected-backgroundcolor-swift/41708160

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can try this one,

```
extension CWScoreBoardViewController: UITableViewDelegate {

  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
      tableView.deselectRow(at: indexPath, animated: true)
  }

}
```

or you can try this,

```
extension CWScoreBoardViewController: UITableViewDataSource {

  func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
      let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "CWUsersTableViewCell", for: indexPath) as! CWUsersTableViewCell

      cell.selectionStyle = .none

      return cell
  }
```

}