# UITableViewCell selected background effect

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview, selected

UITableViewCell default effect, when the cell is pressed, the cell will get gray background.The UITableViewCell child view control will also change the background color.
How to let the child views background doesn't change?

Comment: Similar to this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26895370/swift-uitableviewcell-selected-background-color-on-multiple-selection?rq=1

Comment: I look at the website you provide, the effect is not what I want.But still want to thank you.

Answer (score 0):

This may be suitable for you:

```
[cell setSelectionStyle:UITableViewCellSelectionStyleNone];
```

Comment: I need to effect: when a cell is pressed, the background color is grey.Loosen the finger cell back to the original effect.

Answer (score 0):

Use this code,

```
let cell:UITableViewCell = UITableViewCell(style:UITableViewCellStyle.Default, reuseIdentifier:"cell")

cell.selectionStyle = UITableViewCellSelectionStyle.None
return cell
```

hope its helpful

Comment: I need to effect: when a cell is pressed, the background color is grey.Loosen the finger cell back to the original effect

Comment: you need effects use this, **didSelectRowAtIndexPath:** method

    'tableView.deselectRowAtIndexPath(indexPath, animated: true)'

Comment: This way I know, but the child views set the background color of the cell and presented the above problems.

Comment: try to change the cell content background color

Comment: UITableViewCell, under the finger press, what method is called?

Comment: if you finger press the UITableViewCell called **didSelectRowAtIndexPath:** method.

Comment: I just tested.When the fingers touch up cell, didSelectRowAtIndexPath: method is called