# ASTableNode setSelected Change Background Color of ASDisplayNode in ios

Tags: ios, swift, tableview, asyncdisplaykit

I have used [AsyncDisplayKit](https://github.com/facebookarchive/AsyncDisplayKit) in my ios application. I am using ASTableNode of  ASCellNode using ASVideoNode. It looks like perfect & working fine. But problem occurs when i enabled allowsMultipleSelectionDuringEditing and Select Row its change BackgroundColor of ASVideoNode.

How can i solve this ?

Answer (score 0):

It's UIKit feature try use custom view node under ASVideoNode as background view and change color in it, and overwrite setSelected methods. And try google this question by UIKit https://stackoverflow.com/a/3177264/887325

Comment: @NimishaRanipa can you share a small example project?

Comment: Thank for your help. But i try another way to solve my problem and after my own different solution now its working fine.